# Big-O running time analysis (for loop)

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
   for (j = 0; j < i*i; j++)
      for (k = 0; k < j; k++)
         sum++;
```

Is (1+2+...+((m-1)^2 -1)+ (m-1)^2) = (m-1)^2 *((m-1)^2 + 1) / 2 = O(m^4) correct? If not, can you help me find the true solution and answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here we have

```
sum(i=0..m, sum(j=0..i^2, sum(k=0..j, 1))) =
= sum(i=0..m, sum(j=0..i^2, j)) =
= sum(i=0..m, i^2*(i^2 - 1)/2) =
= sum(i=0..m, (i^4 - i^2)/2) =
= sum(i=0..m, (i^4 - i^2))/2
```

which is `O(m^5)` according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20i%5E4%20-%20i%5E2%2C%20i%3D0%20to%20m).

Looks like you've calculated only the result of the last iteration of the outer loop.

[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28sum%20%28sum%201%2C%20k%3D0%20to%20j-1%29%2C%20j%3D0%20to%20i*i-1%29%2C%20i%3D0%20to%20%28m%20-%201%29) is the precise calculation by Wolfram Alpha which, again, proofs the `O(m^5)` result